# Qt "module "QtQuick.Controls" is not installed"

Tags: qt5, qt

Привет всем! Создал файл qml, в нем пытался подключить компоненты:

`import QtQuick 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0`

В итоге получаю ошибку: module "QtQuick.Controls" is not installed

Qt:5.2.1 
QtCreator:3.0.1

**Вопрос**: как это можно лечить? В при подключении контролов(import QtQuick.Controls 1.0) в редакторе появляются новые элементы..., но почему он тогда выдает ошибку...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В справке [явно сказано](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtquickcontrols/qtquickcontrols-index.html) что для своей работы QtQuick.Controls требуют QtQuick 2.1, а вы подключили 1.1, дело скорее всего в этом